# How do I get value of a property of a json with name starting with $ sign

Tags: javascript, typescript

I receive a json in this format
`{$value: "actualValue", $key: "name"}` 
What I want to get is the string "actualValue". How do I get that value ? 
Let's say the object is obj.
I tried `obj.$value`, `obj[$value]`, `obj["value"]` Nothing seems to work.

Comment: `obj['$value']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literal property:

`obj['$value']`